# Error 2 Class 'WindowsApplication1.ManagementObject' cannot be indexed because it has no default property

Tags: vb.net

```
Public Class frm_SMSconnectionSetting
    Public Shared Comm_Port As Int16 = 0
    Public Shared Comm_BaudRate As Int32 = 0
    Public Shared Comm_TimeOut As Int32 = 0
    Public Shared comm As GsmCommMain
    Private dataSet As DataSet, dataSet1 As New DataSet()
    Private _queryObj As Object

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

    Private Property queryObj(p1 As String) As Object
        Get
            Return _queryObj
        End Get
        Set(value As Object)
            _queryObj = value
        End Set
    End Property


    Private Sub button9_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles button9.Click
        'Setting the column grid for fetched data
        dataGridView3.ColumnCount = 5
        dataGridView3.Columns(0).Name = "COM Port"
        dataGridView3.Columns(1).Name = "Connected Device"
        dataGridView3.Columns(2).Name = "Max Baud Rate"
        dataGridView3.Columns(3).Name = "Time Out"
        dataGridView3.Columns(4).Name = "Status"
        dataGridView3.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.DisplayedCells

        Try
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor
            Dim searcher As New ManagementObjectSearcher("root\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_SerialPort")
            For Each queryObj As ManagementObject In searcher.[Get]()
                If queryObj IsNot Nothing Then
                    Dim captionObj As Object = queryObj("DESCRIPTION")
                    Dim capdeviceid As Object = queryObj("DEVICEID")
                    Dim MaxBaudRate As Object = queryObj("MAXBAUDRATE")
                    Dim connstatus As Object = queryObj("STATUS")
                    Dim timeoutsec As String = "100"
                    dataGridView3.Rows.Add(capdeviceid, captionObj, MaxBaudRate, timeoutsec, connstatus)
                End If
            Next
        Catch e15 As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while querying for WMI data: " + e15.Message)
        End Try
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.[Default]
        button9.Enabled = False
        button10.Enabled = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub frm_SMSconnectionSetting_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        button10.Enabled = False
        lblConnected.Visible = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub button10_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles button10.Click
        Try
            If Not comm.IsConnected() Then
                MessageBox.Show("No Phone Connected", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
                lblNotConnect.Visible = True
                lblConnected.Visible = False
                Return
            Else
                comm.Close()
                lblNotConnect.Visible = True
                lblNotConnect.Visible = False
                button9.Enabled = True
                button10.Enabled = False
                dataGridView3.Rows.Clear()
                Phone_Model.Text = "....."
                Phone_Name.Text = "....."
                Revision_Num.Text = "....."
                Serial_Num.Text = "....."
                MessageBox.Show("Disconnected Successfully", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            End If
        Catch No_Conn As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("No Phone Connected")
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please consider reformatting you code and writing a small introduction to your problem. Also please post the whole error message and what you actually want to happen. Like this it is hard to understand what you are struggling with. For future reference please take a look  at the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: Please also take the time to have a look at [ask] and [mcve] They are very useful pages to help you along here.